# Emacs ansi-term as a login shell

Tags: shell, emacs, rvm

I am using Emacs Live. How can I configure emacs ansi-term to allow login shell? When I try to switch rvm gemsets I get the following message:

```
RVM is not a function, selecting rubies with 'rvm use ...' will not work.
    You need to change your terminal emulator preferences to allow login shell.
    Sometimes it is required to use `/bin/bash --login` as the command.
    Please visit https://rvm.io/integration/gnome-terminal/ for a example.
```

Thanks!

Comment: I think I had the same problem when I was trying Ruby some while ago.
Add this line to your `~/.bashrc` : `PATH=$PATH:$HOME/.rvm/bin`

Comment: Voting to leave open, as Emacs and RVM definitely are "software tools commonly used by programmers", as per the [help/on-topic].

Answer (score 3):

I found that if I add the following line, Emacs will find RVM as a function and stop complaining.

```
# Load RVM into a shell session *as a function*
[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm"
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried this with Linux Mint 20.2, rvm 1.29.12, and GNU Emacs 27.2 and found if I added this to my bashrc:

```
[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/environments/default" ]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/environments/default"
```

Then ansi-term played well with RVM.